# How to hide active character counter in Flask-WTforms StringField and materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am seeing a small counter which shows number of characters typed. I want to hide that counter.
There is no Length Validators in my forms.

I have tried making it to textareafield but the same thing persists

I want to hide the highlighted thing

[image]

```
<body >
<div class="container card centered">
    <form method="POST" action="">
     <h1 class="container">Login</h1>
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        <div class="container">
            {{form.username.label()}} 
            {{form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
        </div> 

        <div class="container">
            {{form.password.label(class="form-control-label")}} 
            {{form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
        </div>     

        <div>
        {{form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info")}}
        </div>    
    </form>
</div>
```

This is Html

```
class User_Form(FlaskForm):
username=StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
password=PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
submit=SubmitField('Login')
```

This is the form

Comment: I can't see any reason why it is appearing. Maybe see page source and or inspect element and see in which element it is appearing as i only see normal bootstrap items around.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Made a CSS  to hide character-counter class